# Lucene.NET indexing files

Tags: search, indexing, lucene.net

What's the best way of indexing pages? I'm creating about 50/60 new pages a day to my website.

Should I index the page when it's created or run a schedule every 15 mins and index in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it would depend on if you are updating the pages as well...if you can handle indexing them when changing them that would be fine but at 50/60 pages a day it doesn't seem like your amount of files would cause any problems on a scheduled index.

Comment: Ideally, i would like to index the page when it's created or reindex when it's updated but not sure if that would slow the site.

I would also like to know when new file is getting index and the index file is locked will it cause problem when someone trying to search the site? .. basically can you still search the site while lucence is indexing a page? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it should index fast enough that you wouldn't even notice. I'd bet that you would be fine indexing when it's updated or added without seeing a performance hit to your site.